# Stacks are executable even with `noexecstack`

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, glibc

I'm trying to protect my application against buffer overflow exploits. Among other things, I'm using non-executable stacks and link my binaries with the `noexecstack` flag (by passing `-Wl,-z,noexecstack` to gcc).

Everything seems fine - `readelf` confirms that `PT_GNU_STACK` specifies correct permissions:

```
$ readelf -l target | grep -A1 GNU_STACK
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
```

So does `execstack`:

```
$ execstack -q target
- target
```

There's only one problem. All my stacks are actually executable:

```
root@170ubuntu16p04-64smp-1:~# cat /proc/12878/task/*/maps | grep stack
7ffcac654000-7ffcac675000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fe540e66000-7fe541666000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fe540665000-7fe540e65000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fe53b800000-7fe53c000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
```

I've trapped [allocate_stack](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/nptl/allocatestack.c#L456) calls and examined protection flags. [In theory](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/elf/rtld.c#L1057), they should be initialized according to `PT_GNU_STACK`. But in my case, it seems like `PT_GNU_STACK` was ignored and `_dl_stack_flags` was initialized with default permissions.

Does anyone know what could have caused this? Everything seems correct, but stacks are still executable.

I'm using gcc 4.8.3 / glibc 2.11.

Comment: Is that a multi-threaded application?

Comment: That option just tags the executable, but it does not guarantee your OS pays attention to it. It's likely not a programming problem, but system administration/configuration.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, it's a multi-threaded application. Stacks are allocated by `pthread_create`.

Comment: @Olaf The OS pays attention to it. I've built several applications using the same toolchain and they don't have executable stacks - stacks are `mmap`ed as `rw-p`. That's why I think I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Well, you might use a library/object file which does not set that flag. That way, the whole application cannot.

Comment: @Olaf That's a great suggestion! I'll try it now.

Comment: Where [dl_stack_flags is used](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/nptl/allocatestack.c#L591) there is an important comment.  _There might have been a race.  **Another thread might have
      caused the stacks to get exec permission while this new
      stack was prepared.**  Detect if this was possible and
      change the permission if necessary._

Comment: You should compile with both `-Wtrampolines` and `-Wl,-z,noexecstack`. They are mutually exclusive, and you will silently lose your NX-stack if a trampoline is present. You should also pass `-Wa,--noexecstack` if you are invoking the assembler. I believe that can cause a loss of NX-stacks, too.

Comment: @LP - Good find. That sounds like a CVE...

Comment: @NikitaKakuev - What is mapped at those addresses? Are they shared objects that lack NX-stacks?

Comment: @LPs I'm pretty sure that's not my case - I have a huge time window between thread launches. But I'll investigate, thanks.

Comment: @jww Those are stacks, `mmap`ed by `allocate_stack`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Olaf and Employed Russian pushed me in the right direction. A third-party shared object was poisoning my stacks.

But it wasn't linked to my main executable directly. Both `ldd` and `lddtree` weren't showing any libraries with RWE stacks, so I've decided to dig deeper and wrote a script that checked all shared objects currently mapped into a process memory:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <target>"
    exit 1;
fi

kav_pid=`pidof $1`
for so in `cat /proc/$kav_pid/task/*/maps | awk '/.so$/ {print $6}' | sort | uniq`; do
    stack_perms=`readelf -Wl $so | awk '/GNU_STACK/ {print $7}'`
    if [ -z "$stack_perms" ]; then
        echo "$so doesn't have PT_GNU_STACK"
    elif [ "$stack_perms" != "RW" ]; then
        echo "$so has unexpected permissions: $stack_perms"
    fi
done
```

And it worked! I found a library with RWE permissions:

```
$ ./find_execstack.sh target
/target/dir/lib64/lib3rdparty.so has unexpected permissions: RWE
```

To make sure that it was this library that poisoned my stacks, I opened my application with `gdb` and set a breakpoint in `dlopen`. And Bingo! Here are the permissions before `dlopen`ing lib3rdparty.so:

```
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
```

And here are they right after the `dlopen`:

```
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
```

As it turned out, `lib3rdparty.so` was built using a different toolchain and that went unnoticed utill now.

Olaf, Employed Russian, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> what could have caused this?

In addition to the main executable's `PT_GNU_STACK` having correct permissions, you *also* need to have `PT_GNU_STACK` with correct permissions in *every* directly-linked shared library.

If any one of these libraries does not have `PT_GNU_STACK` at all, or has one with executable permissions, it will "poison" all of your stacks with executable permission.

So run

```
for j in $(ldd target | grep -o '=> .* ' | sed -e 's/=> //' -e '/^ *$/d' ); do
  out=$(readelf -Wl $j | grep STACK)
  [[ -z "$out" ]] &&  echo "missing GNU_STACK in $j"
  echo $out | grep -q RWE && echo "executable GNU_STACK in $j"
done
```

and you will likely see at least one library with missing or executable stack.

P.S. I see that Olaf has already (partially) suggested this.